# Wordpress session start front end

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create plugin in wordpress.. Plugin data direct to wordpress front end and I want stat wordpress session in front end using the plugin.

I tried using this but this is not working, can someone help me

```
function register_session()
{
  session_start();
}
add_action('init', 'register_session', 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your plugin or themes' functions.php template:

```
function register_session(){
if( !session_id() ) //checking if session already exists
    session_start();
}
add_action('init','register_session');
```

Then to set the session data use something like this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'some data';
```